# Redux toolkit and createAsyncThunk not working with axios instance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, create-react-app, redux-toolkit

I have a react/typescript project. I'm using redux to manage state.

```
//store.ts
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { userReducer } from './user';

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer
})

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: RootReducer,
  devTools: true,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

I also have a userSlice.ts file:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { signIn, signUp } from './../../services/api';
import type { UserCredential, UserInitialState } from './types';

const initialState: UserInitialState = {
  accessToken: null,
  status: 'init',
  user: {
    id: '',
    email: '',
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    isAuthorized: false,
    imported: false,

    teamId: '',
    role: '',
    linkedinLink: null,
    isReceivingNotifications: false,
    avatarKey: null,
    loggedInAt: '',
    createdAt: '',
    updatedAt: '',
    deletedAt: null,
  },
};

const signUpRequest = createAsyncThunk('user/signUpRequest', async (data: UserCredential) => {
  const response = await signUp(data);
  return response.data;
});

const signInRequest = createAsyncThunk('user/signInRequest', async (data: UserCredential) => {
  const response = await signIn(data);
  return response.data;
});

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logOut() {
      return initialState;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(signInRequest.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.status = 'pending';
    });
    builder.addCase(signInRequest.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const { user, accessToken } = action.payload;
      return { accessToken, ...user };
    });
  },
});

export const userSliceActions = {...userSlice.actions};
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

In this slice I use two functions from the API (**signIn, signUp**)

These functions are described in the next file:

```
//api.ts
import { UserCredential } from '../store/user/types';
import { AxiosPromise } from 'axios';
import ApiClient from './ApiClient';

export const signUp = (data: UserCredential): AxiosPromise => {
  return ApiClient.post('v1/auth/sign_up', { data });
};

export const signIn = (data: UserCredential): AxiosPromise => {
  return ApiClient.post('v1/auth/sign_in', { data });
};
```

Above i used simple axios instance from ApiClient.ts file

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
import { store } from '../store/store';
const baseUrl = 'https://************/api';// valid url

class ApiClient {
  private api: AxiosInstance;

  constructor() {
    this.api = axios.create({
      baseURL: baseUrl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    this.api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      const token = store.getState().user.accessToken;
      if (token !== null) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      }
      return config;
    });
  }

  post(url: string, { data }: AxiosRequestConfig) {
    return this.api.post(url, data);
  }

  get(url: string) {
    return this.api.get(url);
  }

  put(url: string, { data }: AxiosRequestConfig) {
    return this.api.put(url, data);
  }

  delete(url: string) {
    return this.api.delete(url);
  }
}

export default new ApiClient();
```

It is worth noting that I try to get the token, if it exists, then write it to the header on every request.

As a result, my store is not initialising (it is empty). In the console I have errors:

1. No reducer provided for key "user"
2. Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

Project structure:

[Project structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AGN2.jpg)

**NOTE 1:**
If I remove the API call inside the userSlice.ts, the errors disappear and the store is working. In this form, everything starts, but I need API calls inside the userSlice...

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import type { UserCredential, UserInitialState } from './types';

const initialState: UserInitialState = {
  accessToken: null,
  status: 'init',
  user: {
    id: '',
    email: '',
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    isAuthorized: false,
    imported: false,
    teamId: '',
    role: '',
    linkedinLink: null,
    isReceivingNotifications: false,
    avatarKey: null,
    loggedInAt: '',
    createdAt: '',
    updatedAt: '',
    deletedAt: null,
  },
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logOut() {
      return initialState;
    },
  },
});

export const userSliceActions = { ...userSlice.actions };
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Do you use `combineReducers`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I tried to add combineReducer function, but the error persists.

Comment: Please remove the API call, streamline the code, locate the problem

Comment: @slideshowp2, Hmm, strange. If i remove api call inside the userSlice.ts, errors disappear, store is working.

Comment: @slideshowp2
I also noticed that if I do not touch the api calls from the userSlice, but remove the interceptor from the apiClient, then everything works. But I need a token for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm stupid! Redux docs does not recommend import store in non-component files. I quote **"You should avoid importing the store directly into other codebase files. While it may work in some cases, that often ends up causing circular import dependency errors."**
This is my case, i imported store to ApiClient.ts file, wooops. Following the documentation, I used the injectStore function. I share the link https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files

Comment: Nice, it working for me.